# How do I manually send a password reset request in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, email, passwords

I would like to manually send a password reset request to a specific user (not the one currently logged in) from within a controller. I did some digging around in the Laravel code and it seems like I should be calling `postEmail(Request $request)` in `ResetsPasswords`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get access to the right `PasswordController` instance to call it.

Comment: Have you tried including the trait by doing `use ResetsPasswords;` inside your controller and then calling the relevant method from the trait?

Comment: @Jonathon Yes. I've used `use ResetsPasswords;` and `$this->postEmail($request);`. There is no output; neither error nor success but I never receive an email.

Comment: update your auth.php configuration file driver

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Why not just something like this for your controller:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $credentials = ['email' => $email_address];
        $response = Password::sendResetLink($credentials, function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't really explain the context of how you want to send this, so adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - this got me on the right track! I just edited the post to make it clear that the first argument to sendResetLink is supposed to be an array of the form `['email' => $email_address]`

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!

Comment: you saved my day, mate!

Comment: I got some error. "Route [password.reset] not defined" .

Comment: Works very well.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to Mariusz Kurman, I only added token to his answer. this works just fine:

```
$user = User::where('email', request()->input('email'))->first();
$token = Password::getRepository()->create($user);
$user->sendPasswordResetNotification($token);
```

Answer (score 18):

Complete control for Laravel 5.5:

```
    $user = User::where('email', request()->input('email'))->first();
    $token = Password::getRepository()->create($user);

    Mail::send(['text' => 'emails.password'], ['token' => $token], function (Message $message) use ($user) {
        $message->subject(config('app.name') . ' Password Reset Link');
        $message->to($user->email);
    });
```

Comment: Cheers for the Password::getRepository()->create();
Also, this worked on 5.4 as well.

Comment: Same as @SuperNOVA: thanks, and it also works on 5.8.

Comment: And here’s the link `href` to put in the mail: `{{ route('nova.password.reset', ['token' => $token ]) }}`

Comment: @kjdion84 why `Password::getRepository()->create($user)` and not just `Password::createToken($user)` - see src https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L205

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way:

```
    $token = Str::random(60);
    $user = User::where('email', request()->input('email'))->first();
    $user->sendPasswordResetNotification($token);
```

[@Doc's bottom](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passwords)

And if you want to edit your e-mail manually:

```
    php artisan vendor:publish
```

select "11"
gives you:

```
/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php
```

Comment: You're using a '$token' variable that's not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for send password reset link.  here i am **API Route** for this.

```
  $this->validate($request, [
        'user_id'    => 'required|int',
    ]);

    $user =  User::find($request->user_id);
    if( $user )
    {
        $credentials = ['email' => $user->email];
        $response = Password::sendResetLink($credentials, function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return response()->json([
                    'status'        => 'success',
                    'message' => 'Password reset link send into mail.',
                    'data' =>''], 201);
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return response()->json([
                    'status'        => 'failed',
                    'message' =>   'Unable to send password reset link.'
                ], 401);
        }  
    }
    return response()->json([
        'status'        => 'failed',
        'message' =>   'user detail not found!'
    ], 401);
```

for Web View :

```
$response = Password::sendResetLink($credentials, function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

       switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
        }
```